# How to insert value of type DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In my table, I have two columns `StartedDate` and `EndDate`, both of them are defined as `Date` datatype.

I am trying to insert values for these two columns via a textfield of type date as shown below:

```
<asp:Textbox type="date" ID="startDate" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Textbox type="date" ID="endDate"  runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value from these textboxes and insert them into my database.

This is my code for the insert:

```
// Insert a new row in the Task table
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Task"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTask")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["StartedDate"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("startDate")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["EndDate"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("endDate")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Done"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DoneCbx")).Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Priority"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("PriorityTxt")).Text;

// Method to execute the insert 
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Insert works just fine, except for the date fields because the value retrieved from the textbox needs to be converted to `DateTime`.

I tried `Convert.ToDateTime` and `Datetime.Parse` methods, but both times I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for the table.

Comment: @mjwills CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskTable] (
    [ToDoId]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Task]        VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [StartedDate] DATE          NULL,
    [EndDate]     DATE          NULL,
    [Done]        BIT           NULL,
    [Priority]    INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ToDoId] ASC)
);

Comment: With the code **as is in your question** - a) does it compile sucessfully? b) does it run? c) what **exactly** isn't working with it?

Comment: @mjwills If I don't add values for start date and end date ( they can be null ) then it works fine.  But I cannot insert the date values, if I do, it throws an exception: system.formatexception string was not recognized as a valid datetime on line 32   
which is the SqlDataSource1.Insert()

Comment: Do what the below answer says - but call `ToString` on the result like in the duplicate. To be clear - you should avoid the use of `SqlDataSource` since it is crap (one of the reasons it is crap is the issue you just ran into).

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) method:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["StartedDate"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Parse(((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("startDate")).Text);
```

Comment: I did try that as mentioned in the question post.  I got the following error: Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'